# In TFS is it possible to make a query that returns all work items where all predecessors are in the closed or resolved state?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to create a query in TFS that allows me to view only Work Items that currently are ready to be worked on (all preceding work items are closed or resolved). Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TFS2010 you have the option to query on the Direct Links. You should be able to achieve with this query type what you want.

I have 5 tasks:

Task 1 is an active task
Task 2 is a closed task

Task 3 has Task 1 as predecessor (link type = predecessor)
Task 4 has Task 2 as predecessor 
Task 5 has Task 1 and 2 as predecessor

Based on your requirement you only want to see task 1 and 3.

You can now create the following query:

[image]

Comment: I would as well. I have played around with Direct Links and cannot seem to achieve the functionality I am looking for.